# Add text to beginning and end of a gziped file

Tags: bash, shell

Using shell scripting : How to add a text in the start and end of an gzipped file with out un-gzipping

My gzipped looks something like below:

```
<record>ABC</record>
<data>DFC</data>
```

After adding header and footer it should look like

```
<xtr>
<record>ABC</record>
<data>DFC</data>
</xtr>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Gzipped files can be joined as if they were normal text files:

```sh
cat <(gzip <<< '<xtr>') file.gz <(gzip <<< '</xtr>') > new.gz
```

The above command is almost equal to the following:

```sh
gzip <<< '<xtr>' > tmpA.gz
gzip <<< '</xtr>' > tmpB.gz
cat tmpA.gz file.gz tmpB.gz > new.gz
```

You can combine it with `sponge` to get rid of the temporary file:

```sh
cat <(gzip <<< '<xtr>') file.gz <(gzip <<< '</xtr>') | sponge file.gz
```

The use of `<()` is [process substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and the use of `<<<` is [here-string](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html).

Comment: when i execute this command i get an error :
./runchecker.sh: line 177: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./runchecker.sh: line 177: `  cat <(gzip <<< '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xtr>') $REPORTS_DIR/$filename"_temp" <(gzip <<< '</xtr>') > $REPORTS_DIR/$filename'

Comment: @Neethu your command runs my on my machine. Would you please run it as `bash -x runchecker.sh` and paste output around the error as well as the code around line 177?